# Adding distinct sum and count columns based on another to datatable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, count, distinct

I have an extra large DataTable (from delimited string cell in my PostgreSQL DB) with ~40k rows. Example data columns:

```
invoice   customer_id     amount
1         1               150,50
2         1               149,50
3         2               50,50
4         3               49,50
```

I'm trying to add 2 columns to this DataTable. One should show number of invoices (customer_id count), but the other one - sum of amount for every customer like this:

```
invoice   customer_id     amount    invoice_count   amount_total
1         1               150,50    2               300,00
2         1               149,50    2               300,00
3         2               50,50     1               50,50
4         3               49,50     1               49,50
```

Using this:

```
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
   Dim distinctDT As DataTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "customer_id", "amount")
   distinctDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "customer_id = " & dt.Rows(i).Item("customer_id")
   dt.Rows(i).Item("count") = distinctDT.DefaultView.Count
Next
```

works, but takes very long time (whole DataTable fills in about 2 hours!) because for every 'i' auxiliary datatable is created (I think so). In Postgres I could use simply `count(customer_id) over(partition by customer_id)` in Select and group by `customer_id` and my query results displayed in few seconds.

Is it possible to solve this problem without creating distinct datatable and filtering it every 'i' ticking? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a query to update that data and a trigger to do the update I think it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the power of LINQ, in this case combined with a `Lookup(Of TKeyx, TValue)` which is similar to a dictionary. It is efficient and makes the code concise and easy to read:

```
Dim customerLookup = dt.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(Function(r) r("customer_id"))
         
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim customerRows = customerLookup(row("customer_id"))
    row("count") = customerRows.Count()
    row("amount_total") = customerRows.Sum(Function(r)row.Field(Of Decimal)("amount"))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works really fast with counting customers, but I cannot build my last sum column (amount total) as I wrote above with double/decimals Could You help me? I'm total beginner in LINQ, but I see that have to learn it asap.

Comment: @DARIUS: I have modifed my answer to show a different approach that combines the power of a dictionary(which the lookup is) and LINQ.

Comment: This solution was really godlike! I had small issues with column type detection in my DT after filling it from delimited string (numeric data was detected as string) but it was easy to solve. Just had to add data type in adding columns section "With"  like: .Columns.Add("amount", GetType(Decimal)). Thank You so much! You deserve a big beer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the beer, i'm glad it helped. You can accept the answer if your question is solved